# Navigator.vibrate() is not working in laptop

Tags: javascript, navigation, frontend, web-deployment, vibration

I am trying to implement Vibrate on my laptop using  `window.navigator.vibrate(200);`.
I am getting **true** in my browser console, however, my laptop is not vibrating.
It should be **false** if it's not vibrating.
Is there any functionality to implement vibrate on a laptop?

Comment: `navigator.vibrate()` returns false if *the argument you supplied is invalid*, not if the device has no vibration capability. In the latter case it simply has no effect but it would still return `true`, given a correct argument.

Comment: is it possible to vibrate to a laptop using `window.navigator.vibrate(200);`?

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, stupid me, it's written right in the beginning of that MDN docpage. :) Not sure how Firefox does this, but Chrome actually doesn't seem to care about parameter.

Comment: Confirmed, Firefox returns `true` both for `navigator.vibrate(-1)` and `navigator.vibrate(NaN)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a nice area of investigation, as the [MDN docpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate) is quite vague on the subject. I mean, talking about "method was unable to vibrate because of invalid parameters" without actually telling what IS invalid parameters - is it normal these days MDN?

The answer might be given in [the standard itself](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#vibration-interface):

> If the result of running the steps to determine the visibility state
>   [PAGE-VISIBILITY-2] is not visible, then return false and terminate
>   these steps.

Unless the implementing teams (making sure the standard is followed by the browsers they develop) got *really creative* there, they only support this case.

---

> Is there any functionality to implement vibrate on a laptop?

I don't think it's possible to implement vibrate on laptop if it doesn't have the hardware means to do it. But if it has some, it should be controllable through something similar to `android.permission.VIBRATE` permissions - set to false by default. It wouldn't be a good idea if any page could send my laptop into Harlem Shake mode.

Comment: "*without actually telling what IS invalid parameters*" given that the method expects either a number (signifying milliseconds) or an array of numbers, I don't think it's really needed to provide an exhaustive list of invalid parameters, as it should be implicit: negative numbers, non-numbers, or arrays containing negative numbers or non-numbers. I'm pretty sure that's the style of most of the documentation on MDN - it tells you what's *valid* and might mention what happens if it's invalid but doesn't necessarily need to enumerate all invalid inputs.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm fine with describing invalid as something that's not valid; the problem is, it's not given either. Yes, we can guess that "Each value indicates a number of milliseconds to vibrate or pause, in alternation" _most probably_ means that the number should be non-negative integer - but it's never written down explicitly. And anyway, it's wrong - just run Firefox to check; both navigator.vibrate(-1) and navigator.vibrate(NaN) return `true` just fine.

Comment: What about the example code given? Also, if the value signifies milliseconds, why would it be valid to provide negative numbers or anything else? This isn't really like `setTimeout` where the minimum delay is capped at 40ms. Even then MDN [does not specify that the delay must not be negative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). It does have a provision for the cap but it doesn't describe what's *invalid* nor does it explicitly say what's *valid*. Since the parameter is for milliseconds, it doesn't need to, either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how one example when the documentation is not detailed is a good defense for another such case, to be honest. ) As for examples, I treat them as unit tests essentially - and I'm highly doubtful in this particular case we're even close to that dreaded 80% limit.

Comment: And just to clarify: yes, good documentation doesn't mean perfect, it usually means good enough. If that were the case here, I don't think we would have this discussion.

Comment: Feel free to change it, then - MDN is a public wiki, after all. To me, "milliseconds" is exceptionally clear that it means non-negative integers but you can make is more specific if that's what you expect. Point is that your complaining here is useless.